# Limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to -3} \frac {4^\frac{x+3}{5}-1}{x+3}$, without L'Hopital's rule.

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried substituting $x+3$ to see if I could simplify in any way, but couldn't think of anything. Also tried using $\ln$ and $\exp$, but in the end just got to $\ln(0)$. Can someone give me a tip?

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

Are you acquainted to the derivative definition?

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to-3}\frac{4^{\frac{x+3}{5}} - 1}{x + 3} = \lim_{x\to-3}\frac{4^{\frac{x+3}{5}} - 4^{\frac{-3 + 3}{5}}}{x - (-3)}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: To be honest, not really, since my class has only gone up until limits until now... But I looked it up and the idea is manipulating it to fit into the derivative definition?

Comment: @LuanArita That is the point. If you still need further assistance, please let me know.

Comment: Aah I see, that's a fancy solution! Out of curiosity, is there any other "conventional" way of solving it? (i.e. algebraic manipulation or subst.)

Comment: @LuanArita you can check out Frank's solution, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a proof without using derivatives: Observe that our limit is also equal to

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-3}\frac {4^{(x+3)/5}-1}{x+3}=\frac 15\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac {4^x-1}x$$

Where the substitution $x\mapsto\tfrac 15(x+3)$ was made. The resulting limit can be tackled by using another substitution

$$n=4^x-1\qquad\implies\qquad x=\log_4(n+1)$$

Therefore, when $x$ tends towards zero, $n$ also tends towards zero. Substituting gives

$$\begin{align*}\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac {4^x-1}x & =\lim\limits_{n\to0}\frac {n}{\log_4(n+1)}\\ & =\lim\limits_{n\to0}\frac 1{\log_4(n+1)^{1/n}}\end{align*}$$

Now use the limit definition of $e$

$$e=\lim\limits_{n\to0}(n+1)^{1/n}$$

To get

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac {4^x-1}x=\frac 1{\log_4 e}=\log 4$$

Note that $\log(\cdot)$ is the natural logarithm. Our original limit is $1/5$ of that, so we get

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-3}\frac {4^{(x+3)/5}-1}{x+3}\color{blue}{=\frac 15\log 4}$$

Comment: I tried solving it by my own using your thought process, but on the first substitution I substituted $x+3$ instead of $\frac{x+3}{5}$. Which, consequently, led to $n = a^(\frac{4}{5}) - 1$ and $x = ln(n-3)$, which led to

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac {n}{ln(n-3)}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac {1}{ln(x-3)^\frac{1}{x}}$$

In this case, can I still use the limit definition of $e$ somehow? Or I simply picked the wrong substitution?

Comment: @LuanArita Your $\LaTeX$ is a little messed up, but if you substitute in $z=x+3$, then as $x\to-3$, then $z\to0$ so the limit becomes$$\lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac {4^{z/5}-1}{z}$$

Comment: Sorry, I keep hitting "enter" instead of "shift+enter", now it's fixed. I got to where you said, but I'm not sure what to do with my end result, can I still fit it in the limit definition of e?

Comment: @LuanArita I'm not following how you landed at $n/\log(n-3)$. If you start off from my last comment and substitute $n=4^{z/5}-1$, then $z=5\log_4(n+1)$ and $n\to0$, so the limit becomes$$\lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac {4^{z/5}-1}{z}=\lim\limits_{n\to0}\frac n{5\log_4(n+1)}$$Can you post your work/check against mine?

Comment: Ah, I see now. I missed the part where you used $log$ in base 4, whereas I was using $ln$, which made it a lot harder. Thanks!